# How do I fix the error I am getting: "Unexpected token '=' expected expression". working with templates and linked lists

Tags: c++

I am trying to work with a stack of linked lists in a template, and I am getting an error when I try to set the top node of the linked list, to the next value. I don't get this error when I am working with the template, so I know it has to do with that, but I just can't figure out why.

I have tried just taking out the  after top completely to see if that would fix it, but then I am left with a lot more errors saying that I am trying to convert a pointer to a template.

//Here is where I set up the template/class/struct

```
template<typename T>
struct StackNode
{
    T ch;
    StackNode<T> *next;
};
template<typename T>
class StackAsLList
{
private:
    StackNode<T> *top;
public:
    StackAsLList();
    void ClearStack();
    void Push(T ch);
    T Pop();            
    bool isEmpty();     
    bool isFull();      
    ~StackAsLList() 
    {
        ClearStack();
    }
};
```

//here is one of the functions where I get the error

```
template<typename T>
void StackAsLList<T>::ClearStack() {
    struct StackNode *temp;

    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        temp = top;

        /// Scan stack and free all nodes
        while (top != 0)
        {
            temp = top;
            top<T> = top<T>->next;  //specifically this line
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    top = 0;    
}
```

Comment: What do you believe `top<T>` means?

Comment: The top of the linked list and converting it to the value <T> instead of just leaving it as a pointer is what I thought it meant (kind of like casting maybe?).

Comment: That's not how you convert values in C++. If, for example, you have a `double v;` and wish to convert it to `int`, you don't write "`v<int>`". That's not the correct C++ syntax. You need to figure out exactly what you want to do here. `top` is a pointer to something. The only thing you can do to is is to dereference it.

Comment: While `'T'` is for `"Texas"` generally, in C++ templates, `'T'` is for *typename* or *class* which are *type template parameters*, see [Templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates). And... would not appear as `top<T> = top<T>->next;`

Comment: Just use `top = top->value;`.